# Why do my buttons and other elements keep re-arranging in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

I'm building a simple app for a game that has labels, textfields and buttons. Every time I try to run the app the elements on the screen keep moving around in the emulator even if they look find in the editor. [Picture of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J51v.png)

I've tried adjusting them by dragging and dropping and experimenting by changing XML. I think I'm missing something, but is positioning elements on the screen the way you want usually this difficult?

Answer (score 1):

If you use lots of views in vertical direction use Linear layout, if more on horizontal use relative layout as you can position elements left-right or center w.r.t each other or parent easily, use a combination of both to get best results.